# Float image on top when scrool page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, css3

I thinkingif it is possible to detect moments: start scrolling the page and end of this stage in a lightning component.

I trying add top of the page menu with position: fixed; and when I scrool is show but when i stop scrooling i hide it.

This is posible in lightning component?

Comment: Maybye you should use Jquery to this.